# mapbox - why do all my features disappear when I change the map style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox gl js to create some maps.  To style the map, I use the following code;

```
// add a styled map to the contianer id map
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container:  'map', // container ID
  style:      'mapbox://styles/bogdanvectuel/cjq1fxndm5qr02roa06jcfb61',
});
```

Above is a public map style from bogdanvectuel.  I wanted to changed to my own style but when I change over to a mapbox offered style like the outdoors one, all of a sudden all my skiareas points disappear which is defined as follows;

```
    /** Add ski areas but just the center point as source / dot **/
    map.addSource('aa_winter_spoorts_points', {
        type: 'vector',
        // aa_winter_spoorts_points
        url: 'mapbox://username.aa_winter_spoorts_points'
                       
    });

    /** Add ski areas but just the center point as layer / dot **/
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'aa_winter_spoorts_points',
        'type': 'symbol',  // background, fill, line, symbol, raster, circle, fill-extrusion, heatmap, hillshade, sky.
        'source': 'aa_winter_spoorts_points',
        'source-layer': 'skiareas',
        'layout': {
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'icon-image': 'airfield-11',
            'icon-allow-overlap': true
        },
        
    });
```

I cannot understand why that would happen.  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `addSource()` and `addLayer()`, you are manually adding the source and layer to the map's `style`.  Changing to a different style after map load essentially starts over from scratch.  Using `setStyle()` will clear the existing style, so anything you added after map load would need to be added again.

One approach may just be to move your `addSource()` and `addLayer()` calls to a new function like `addCustomSourcesAndLayers()`.  You could then call that after the first map load, and again after `setStyle()`

You can see this in action in [geojson.io](https://geojson.io).  We allow you to switch to a different style and then re-draw the user-defined layers after the new style loads.

Comment: new mapboxgl.Map is the first thing loaded.  Everything works find if I use the bogdanvectuel style.  As I do not have access to this style to change is, I have made my own style.  I have the same line of code to point to my style but then all disappears.